# Big O notation $O(\epsilon)$

Tags: notation

What does it mean to say that $\tau=O(\epsilon)$? Where $\epsilon$ is small, meaning that $\epsilon \ll 1$.

Comment: Have you read the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)? Roughly speaking, it means that the ratio $\frac{\tau}{\varepsilon}$ remains bounded on some interval $(0,a)$, or equivalently that there exists a constant $C>0$ and some $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that $0 \leq \lvert\tau\rvert \leq C\varepsilon$ for all $0 < \varepsilon \leq \varepsilon_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big O notation gives you an upper bound. Saying $f(x)=x+O(\epsilon)$, for example, is saying that f(x)=x plus some error term which is bounded by some constant times epsilon, which is small.

In your case, they are saying that $\tau$ is bounded above by something on the order $\epsilon$ up to a constant